# Session fails after dynamic header redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect, session-variables

I've been struggling with this for a long time and I've read dozens of posts pertaining to it, but nothing has helped me solve this.

I have a check set up so if you're not logged into my site, it sends you to the log in page with a `$_GET` variable containing the information needed to be redirected back after a successful log in.

On the sign in page, I send an HTML form to a "`checklogin.php`" file in order to log in the user if the username and password match the database (I also pass the original `$_GET` variable for the redirect as a `$_POST` variable this time to keep the 'bread crumbs' connected). If the log in info matches, I start a session and assign session variables with some information about the user.

At the bottom of the page, after a successful log in, I do this to get back to where they were before:

```
$go = "http://something/page.php?id=".$_POST['breadcrumb'];
header($go);
```

This works... initially (the session variable is successfully passed to `page.php`). But then the *very next page* a user clicks to go to, the session ends and he/she is no longer logged in.

So frustrating! **The `session_start()` is at the top of every single page.** And the session is successful throughout when the user just logs in without the dynamic header redirect (without the `$_POST['breadcrumb']`).

I've tried many different solutions and nothing fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't keep my url redirects consistent throughout the site. Sometimes I had

```
www.website.com/home.php
```

and sometimes I had

```
/home.php
```

which screwed up the $SESSION.

The solution was to keep my header redirects all consistently without (or all consistently with) "www.website.com" in the beginning of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all the code to make sure there isnt a session destroy in there somewhere? 
You could also try using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; to obtain your redirect url then just insert that into the header code so it would be.

```
header("location: <breadcrumb>);
```